# Error in highstock chart. Data is undefined in tooltip

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to build a highstock chart where I have a set of timestamps in x axis and numbers in y axis. Also I have some other data in the array which I would like to show during in the tooltip. The data array is like below:

```
data=[
{
"ID": 9682533,
"PONumber": "100869279",
"y": 2,
"x": 1470196365449
 },
  ...];
```

and the tooltip formatter function is:

```
tooltip: {

                formatter: function () {

                    console.log('inside formatter');
                    var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y,  %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '</b>';

                    $.each(this.points, function () {
                        s += '<br/> ID:= <b>'
                            + this.point.ID
                            + '</b><br/> Completion time:= <b>'
                            + this.y
                            + ' secs</b><br/>'
                            + 'Purchase Order Number:= <b>'
                            +  this.point.PONumber
                            + '</b><br/>';
                    });

                    return s;

                }
            }
```

When I plot the data however I get the value of ID and Purchase Order Number as undefined. When I zoom the data however I get to see the correct data in tooltip. The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jayadrath/v8mLc8np/. Any help to solve this issue will be great.

**Edit:** Some answers and comments have mentioned that they cannot see the issue. Hence attaching screenshot.

[image: Highstock data issue]

Comment: Dear Kaushik, I do not understand your problem. I am trying your code in jsfiddle and I can see correctly the values of ID and Puchase Order in the tooltip without using the zoom. Please, can you explain in greater detail the problem ?

Comment: Added a screenshot for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also cannot reproduce on your fiddle - tooltip shows and no error on tooltip values undefined in console.

Is the fiddle data all of the data or is this just a sample? I am wondering if the issue has to do with [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) being enabled on your chart and there being much more data. If `dataGrouping` is on there is some approximation done on your x/y values and it probably is not getting your other tooltip items transferred to the point.

Try turning off `dataGrouping`.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work since Highstock is only retrieving and using the x and y values from your data object + you are refering to this.point.ID/PONumber that doesnt exist.

Here is a console.log(this) output of "this".

Object {x: 1470196320000, y: 2, points: Array[1]}

points:Array[1]

x:1470196320000

y:2